# How to use range() with while loop?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, range, maxlength

I need to create an empty list
Ask the user for any input 5 times
Only add the input to the list if it does NOT already exist

I keep getting into an infinity loop instead of only 5 times.

That's my code:

```
MyList = []
maxLengthList = range(5)
while len(MyList) < maxLengthList:
    i = input("Enter a number to the list: ")
    if i not in MyList:
        MyList.append(i)
print("That's your numbers list")
print(MyList)
```

Comment: Why are you using `range`? Just do `while len(MyList) < 5`

Comment: @flakes I did what you said but it loops more than 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper usage of range is:

```
for x in range(start, end):
    print(x)
```

So in your case it would be:

```
# Using underscore here since you do not need the value for each loop
for _ in range(5):
    i = input("Enter a number to the list: ")
    if i not in MyList:
        MyList.append(i)
```

However, you could just set maxLengthList equal to 5 instead of range(5)

Answer (score 0):

You have used the range() function as a constant for max length which is not possible
range(5) = range(0,5) it does not give you a constant to work with
You cannot compare len(MyList) to maxlengthlist
Type(Mylist) = int
Type(MaxLengthlist) = range class

Answer (score 0):

In Python, range is an immutable iterable object similar to a generator.  When you say range(5), it produces numbers from 0 to 4.  You use a for_loop to iterate over a range, not a while_loop.

For your purposes, you don't need range at all.  Your code works perfectly without it.

```
MyList = []
maxLengthList = 5
while len(MyList) < maxLengthList:
    i = input("Enter a number to the list: ")
    if i not in MyList:
        MyList.append(i)
print("That's your numbers list")
print(MyList)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

Try learning about `for` loops. You can use them like this: `for _ in range(5):`. Use them for subscriptable formats. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely study more loops.